# not able to understand behaviour in jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I create a dialog box after clicking on a button and in dialog box i have two checkboxes and one text box.My java script code is as follows:-

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('<form id="verifyform" action=""><input type="checkbox" id="correct" name="correct" value="true" />Tick if Word is valid<br /><input type="checkbox" name="discard"  id="discard" value="true" /> Tick if you want to discard this word <br /><br /><br />If you want change/edit existing word,enter new word in below text box <br /><input type="text" name="new_word" id="new_word" value="" /><br /></form>')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Verify Words',
        buttons: {
            "Submit": function() {  $('form#verifyform').submit();},
            "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
        }
    });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    $('form#verifyform').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var correct_check = $('#correct').is(':checked');
        $("#dialog").dialog();
        $('.insert-data').append('<li>'+correct_check+'</li>');   
        $dialog.dialog('close');
    });
```

My html code is as follows:-

```
<div id="dialog" title="Verify Words"> <ul class="insert-data"></ul></div><button id="getselected" onclick="get_select()">Select row and Verify</button>
```

When i select "correct word check box" in dialog box i get value "true" at first time but when did not select that check box second time stil i got value "true" four times

I am not able to understand this behaviour? How to fix this?
Any help on this matter will be appreciated?

Comment: Try this http://jsbin.com/ahiBAqi/2/ check and uncheck the checkbox and you will see true and false every time you click submit button. Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: thanks! i edided above link and it seems that after checking the check in box still it shows false value

Comment: What is link for the edit you made to above fiddle?